# animating a simple jquery function

Tags: jquery

I have a simple jquery function that resizes a table when it is clicked.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('.expand_table').live("click", function()
            {
                $('.expand_table').attr('width', 800);
            }); 
        });
    </script>
```

How would I build on this to make the table smoothly expand or grow to the new size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't animate an attribute, though. So you'd have to set the size in CSS.. Just switch

```
$('.expand_table').attr('width', 800);
```

for:

```
$('.expand_table').animate({ "width":"800px" }, 500); //uses 500ms to complete
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way I can stop the <tr>'s inside the table from shrinking during the resize? When the animation starts they get very small then when it animation finish pop to full size.

Comment: I haven't looked into animating table sizes, but the `tr`'s shouldn't really pop in and out. Do you mean the `td`'s? You can set up separate animations for the table cells if you want...

Answer (score 0):

Use the animate function with more options

[animate](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate)

```
$(".expand_table").animate({ width: "800px" }, 1500 );
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('.expand_table').live("click", function()
        {
                //$('.expand_table').attr('width', 800);
                $(".expand_table").animate({ width: "800px" }, 1500 );
                // 1500 can be replaced with "slow", "normal", or "fast" or a 
                // number that specifies the speed of the animation
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to here:http://jqueryui.com/docs/Effects/Methods

Lots of example where you can apply on.

Best